# Generic Full Text Search

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, full-text-search

I have a Postgresql database. I am trying to make the following easy:

1. Searching a table that has relationships. I am not sure how to 'index' the relationships. For example:

Suppose I have the following:

```
class Book(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    chapters = relationship("Chapter", backref="book")

class Chapter(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    book_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Book.id))

def generic_search(self, query_string, indexes): 
    
    """
    Search for database tables using ts_vector column and ts_query
    """
    search_term = query_string
    session = self.session

    
     print("Searching ...")

     table = str(indexes[0])
     model_name = self.get_class_by_table_name(table)
        
     query = session.query(model)

      
     query_result = (
            
     try:    
       results = 
        session.query(model_name).filter(model_name.__ts_vector__.match(search_term))
        ).all()
       
           
     except DatabaseError:
        transaction.rollback()
```

Edit:
I want to make `chapters` searchable on the `Books` model (Basically search for a string in the chapters column via the `Books` model.
In short I want to be able to search a table and all it's related tables for a specific string.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, I want to be to search a table and all it's related tables for a specific string.

Answer (score 2):

When using Postgresql as the back end, full text search can be performed using a column's [match](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=tsvector#full-text-search) attribute.  A simple filter would look like

```py
Chapter.name.match(search_term)
```

which is equivalent to the Postgresql expression

```sql
name @@ to_ts_query(search_term)
```

It follows that `search_term` must be in a form that `to_tsquery` will accept<sup>*</sup>.

To find whether a Book contains *any* chapters that match the search term(s) we can do:

```py
with Session() as s:
    result = (
        s.query(Book)
        .filter(
            Book.chapters.any(
                Chapter.name.match(search_term)
            )
        )
        .all()
    )
    print(result)
```

Alternatively, if we want to check which chapters in a particular book match the search terms we could do:

```py
with Session() as s:
    # Get a book
    book = s.get(Book, 1)
    result = (
        s.query(Chapter)
        .filter(
            sa.and_(
                Chapter.book == book,
                Chapter.name.match(search_term),
            )
        )
        .all()
    )
    print(result)
```

The respective queries in SQLAlchemy 2.0 style would be:

```py
with Session() as s:

    # Find books with matching chapters.
    result = s.scalars(
        sa.select(Book).where(
            Book.chapters.any(
                Chapter.name.match(search_term)
            )
        )
    ).all()
    print(result)
    # Find matching chapters for a book.
    result = s.scalars(
        sa.select(Chapter).where(
            sa.and_(
                Chapter.book == book,
                Chapter.name.match(search_term),
            )
        )
    ).all()
    print(result)
```

---

<sup>*</sup> The tip at the end of the linked documentation section provides the sensible advice

> It’s important to remember that text searching in PostgreSQL is powerful but complicated, and SQLAlchemy users are advised to reference the PostgreSQL documentation regarding [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/textsearch-controls.html).